# How should I declare a vector variable in OpenCL that can fully utilize GPU's vectorized feature

Tags: opencl, gpu, vectorization, amd-processor

I'm using AMD-APP (1214.3). My code in OpenCL is as follows,

```
// W is an uint4 variable
uint4 T = (uint4)(1U, 2U, 3U, 4U);
T += W;
```

or I had also tried using constant data as follows,

```
// outside function scope
__constant uint4 X = (uint4)(1U, 2U, 3U, 4U);
// inside function
uint4 T = X;
T += W;
```

However, after compilation I saw the assembly code contains multiple addition instructions to form a uint vector;

```
dcl_literal l16, 0x00000001, 0x00000001, 0x00000001, 0x00000001
dcl_literal l19, 0x00000002, 0x00000002, 0x00000002, 0x00000002
dcl_literal l18, 0x00000003, 0x00000003, 0x00000003, 0x00000003
dcl_literal l17, 0x00000004, 0x00000004, 0x00000004, 0x00000004
    mov r66, l16
    iadd r66, r66.xyz0, l17.000x
    iadd r66, r66.xy0w, l18.00x0
    iadd r66, r66.x0zw, l19.0x00
    iadd r75, r75, r66
```

So, how could I code for vector initialization in OpenCL to achieve fewer instruction. For example, one instruction load and then iadd, like following

```
dcl_literal l16, 0x00000001, 0x00000002, 0x00000003, 0x00000004
   move r66, l16
   iadd r75, r75, r66
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Most GPUs are superscalar these days, it turned out the best way to keep GPUs doing the most amount of useful work on each clock cycle was to ditch having to schedule vector instructions cleverly. They are designed to run a lot of scalar instructions in parallel, and thus I would expect to see disassembled code for a scalar GPU working exactly that way.

Comment: Are you compiling with the optimizations enabled or disabled?

Comment: Only `-D` were specified for compiler directives. Neither `-cl-opt-disable` nor '-O0' used in `clBuildProgram`.

Comment: Which AMD GPU are you using? Is it VLIW (5xxx, 6xxx) or GCN (7xxx) based? Only the former will create vector instructions.

Comment: I'm using HD 78xx GPU. According to AMD OpenCL programming guide, using 4-width vector types(int4, float4, etc) is preferred. However, when I declare `uint4` type, the generated IL `dcl_literal` is like the first assembly code, it duplicates 4 times, and uses 4-width literals to represent my one `uint4` variable. However, I do see  some constant literals of IL looks like my second assembly code which contains 4 different hex numbers. But those constant literals are not my explicit code because I cannot find such number in OpenCL source. However, I think compiler and GPU could support such IL.

Comment: Does `atomic add(...)` has the same behaviour ?

Comment: atomic increment operator does not have this behavior. Not sure the atomic add operator. However, this is only an example, not always the add function.

Answer (score 0):

What you see in

```
dcl_literal l16, 0x00000001, 0x00000001, 0x00000001, 0x00000001
...
```

seems to be LLVM assembler. It's an output of compiler front-end yet to be processed by back end & translated into machine code. As it's not the final version, than, in my opinion, there is no measure to determine how optimal this code is.

*As suggestion* - such LLVM representation may be used for better backward compatibility with legacy architectures, as it looks like VLIW instructions code.

Returning back to OpenCL performance. One IO operation takes so long, that all effort, put into smaller instruction-level optimizations is just wasting of time. That's why GPGPU performance is usually bandwidth - bound.